# Git hook equivalent in RTC SCM

Tags: version-control, githooks, checkin, rational-team-concert, server-side-validation

We have Gitlab configured like following:

1. If anyone pushes their code, first sever side git hook (pre-receive) will trigger SonarQube Quality checks, if any error in code it rejects that push.
2. Also checks for file types, if some files like `.zip`, `.o` or `.class` are present, the code gets rejected by the same server side hook.
3. Same for file size.

Are the above 3 validations possible in IBM RTC SCM before delivering the code to the server? How? I know `.jazzignore`, but I want specifically for server side rules.

We want to know it as we are switching to RTC. We also have hooks to build via Jenkins etc. etc., but I know this is possible in RTC.

Comment: Shouldn't you have checked that the parts of your current workflow that you wanted to retain were supported *before* deciding whether to switch?

Comment: you're so right.... We are influenced by all other tools rqm, ccm, doors etc. And also integration plugin with sonar that time... so we didn't consider much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Rational Team Concert does not have out of box possibility to address those 3 scenarios. You can do it by implementing your own [Operations Behaviors](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.platform.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_behavior.html) (server-side extensions) in Java. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMj9Hf6entc&t=929s)

If you are a huge fan of Git, I recommend using [RTC Git Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAfhEpIrCQE&t=9s) which is quite good.

Comment: I was not looking for ready made cooked procedure. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: My pleasure to help :)